# Am I using the triple product rule correctly?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Am I using the [triple product rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_product_rule) correctly?

The triple product rule states $\displaystyle\left(\frac{\partial x}{\partial y}\right)_z\left(\frac{\partial y}{\partial z}\right)_x\left(\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}\right)_y=-1$

Where each derivative is the partial derivative of one variable with respect to another, while holding the third (outside the brackets) fixed.

If I apply this to $xy=z$ I get:

$\displaystyle\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\left(\frac{-z}{y^2}\right)y=-1$

Which solves to give $-z/xy=-1$

Which all seems to check out
[errata fixed]

Comment: Please, give a reference for the "triple product rule", and where to find definitions of exotic things like $\displaystyle\left(\frac{\delta x}{\delta y}\right)_z$. Without precise definitions, you don't even have a stick in mathematics.

Comment: @ProfessorVector sorry I've added the reference now. I made the mistake of assuming this was a well known identity.

Comment: Then, you didn't even quote it correctly, let alone use. And the symbols you use mean functional derivatives, normally.

Comment: @ProfessorVector thanks, I've spotted my typo. How do I get the d I want?

Comment: Try "\partial y" to get $\partial y$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am afraid this is physicists' notation.

You have $z=xy$.
Then $x=z/y$ and $y=z/x$. So
$$\left(\frac{\partial x}{\partial y}\right)_z=-\frac{z}{y^2},$$
$$\left(\frac{\partial y}{\partial z}\right)_x=\frac{1}{x}$$
and
$$\left(\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}\right)_y=y.$$
Multiplying these together gives
$$-\frac{yz}{xy^2}=-\frac{xy^2}{xy^2}=-1.$$

As for interpreting what the likes of
$\left(\frac{\partial x}{\partial y}\right)_z$ actually mean, good luck!

Comment: Ah yes, I've made a typo. Thanks.

Comment: xy=z plots a 2-d surface.  That derivative gives us the ratio of the change in $x$ with respect to $y$ while we move along an isobar of $z$ on the surface.